# How to delete rows below the last row contains a specified string (last match)? by VBA

Tags: excel, vba, match

Hi I'm searching and trying to merge some VBA codes to overcome my problem but haven't been succesfull so far. What i want to do is search specific words in a Column (i.e. "XxX" this a just a part of that cell) and find the last match, and delete the rows below this row by using VBA. I have 278 txt files needs to be converted into xlsx for applying this in batch. I'm adding an example so maybe I'll explain better.

```
Ağ Teknolojileri Elemanı
Network Technologies Personnel
(Level 5)
12UY0046-5/A1
Occupational Health and Safety, Quality, Work Organization and Professional Development
XxX Explains OHS measures.
XxX Explains environment protection measures.
XxX Defines quality applications.
XxX Explains how to make work organization.
XxX Defines activities needed to be carried out for professional development.
12UY0046-5/A2
Basis of Computer Hardware and Software
XxX Explains the operating logic of the computer.
XxX Explains basic computer use.
XxX Explains the working principles of computer energy hardwares.
XxX Describes the basic features of computer components.
df
fsd
s
gfd
gdfg
dfs
fd
```

Note: All in "A" column.

For this sample I want the VBA code will find the last cell that contains "XxX" (XxX Describes the basic features of computer components.) and delete all the rows below this row.

I don't know if i can do this to txt files. But nevertheless i couldn't find a way to do it for txt files, i need to change those txt files into xlsx.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Option Explicit
Sub delAfter()
    Const sFind As String = "XxX"
    Dim WS As Worksheet, R As Range

'Find last sFind
Set WS = Worksheets("sheet2") 'or ActiveSheet or whatever
With WS.Cells
    Set R = .Find(what:=sFind, _
         after:=.Item(1, 1), _
         LookIn:=xlValues, _
         lookat:=xlPart, _
         searchorder:=xlByRows, _
         searchdirection:=xlPrevious, _
         MatchCase:=True)
    If Not R Is Nothing Then
        Set R = WS.Range(R.Offset(1, 0), .Cells(.Rows.Count, R.Column).End(xlUp))
        R.EntireRow.Delete 'deletes entire row.  If just want a single column, adjust
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Will delete entire rows after finding last `XxX`.
If you examine the code, you will see we start in the first row, but the searchorder is xlprevious so we will be searching from the bottom.

If you need to restrict it to a specific column, just change the range being searched.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks for supporting Ron.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

This code should work for strings containing XxX in columns a

```
Option Explicit

Sub Delete()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long, RowNum As Long
Dim str As String
Dim r As Range, Cell As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Blad1")

str = "XxX"

Lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set r = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(Lastrow, 1))

For Each Cell In r
    If Cell.Value Like "*" & str & "*" Then
        i = Cell.Row
        Exit For
    End If
Next Cell

For RowNum = i + 1 To Lastrow
    ws.Rows(i + 1).Delete
Next RowNum


End Sub
```

Comment: This deletes all rows until 6. row. 1 to 6 rows are there. There is something wrong here. This vba finds the first match not the last one